# QT + VS ：how do i solve this problem ？ error 1：moc

Tags: visual-studio, qt

i used QT5.7.0 + VS 2013 to compile my project， but it output an error：
error 1：moc （C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\bin\moc.exe）
How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please give the complete error? Here you only give the path to the qt moc precompiler.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to update qt-vsaddin or delete the VS related project files and reload the QT project.Hope this solves your problem